# I want to know why $Articles will not be generate

Tags: php, cakephp

In CakePHP tutorial, I want to make Articles, but I do not know.

I am working on [cakePHP](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/cms/database.html),  along this, a error says `Call to a member function find() on boolean`

This is ArticleController

```php
<?php
namespace App\Controller;
use App\Controller\AppController;

class ArticleController extends AppController {
    public function index() {
        $this->loadComponent('Paginator');
        debug($this->Articles);
        $articles = $this->Paginator->paginate($this->Articles->find());
        $this->set(compact('articles'));
    }
    public function edit() {
        $article = $this->Articles->findBySlug($slug)->firstOrFail();
        if ($this->request->is(['post', 'put'])) {
            $this->Articles->patchEntity($article, $this->request->getData());
            if ($this->Articles->save($article)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('Your article has been updated.'));
                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            }
            $this->Flash->error(__('Unable to update your article.'));
        }
        $this->set('article', $article);
    }
    public function view($slug = null)
    {
        $article = $this->Articles->findBySlug($slug)->firstOrFail();
        $this->set(compact('article'));
    }

}
```

This is Article index

```php
<!-- File: src/Template/Articles/index.ctp -->

<h1>Articles</h1>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Created</th>
    </tr>

    <!-- Here is where we iterate through our $articles query object, printing out article info -->

    <?php foreach ($articles as $article): ?>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <?= $this->Html->link($article->title, ['action' => 'view', $article->slug]) ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?= $article->created->format(DATE_RFC850) ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

and this is model.

```php
<?php
// src/Model/Entity/Article.php
namespace App\Model\Entity;

use Cake\ORM\Entity;

class Article extends Entity
{
    protected $_accessible = [
        '*' => true,
        'id' => false,
        'slug' => false,
    ];
}
```

I copied all of them, searched this article a lot, but cannot find 
where the Articles came from.
Please teach me ><

Comment: Your class should be called ArticlesController, not ArticleController, and then the automagic will happen.

Comment: Thank you! I found

Comment: You need to load your Article model on controller.

Comment: This may be caused by a simple typographical error, but it is a non-obvious problem. I've tentatively voted to close, but this question might be useful for others -- I'm not familiar with this framework.

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
class ArticleController extends AppController
```

should be

```
class ArticlesController extends AppController
```

Also, filename should be ArticlesController.php, in my opinion.